# if() statements within nested for() loops

Tags: r, loops, date, dplyr

I'm trying to loop through my data frame to identify a date period for each record/row where a condition is met, then loop back through my data frame to identify every other row that falls within this date period, and finally output this as a new data frame. However, I am having trouble with the nested `for()` loops and am new to writing loops generally. Any help/advice appreciated.

Example data

```
# Set seed
set.seed(5)

# Create data
example.dat1 <- data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 20), 
                           Latitude = sample(seq(34, 36, by=0.0001), 20),
                           Longitude = sample(seq(114, 117, by=0.0001), 20),
                           rhdv =  round(runif(20, 0, 1), digits = 0),
                           control.any = round(runif(20, 0, 1), digits = 0))

# Filter to obtain records of interest
example.dat1 <- filter(example.dat1, control.any == 1 | (control.any == 0 & rhdv == 1))

# Create some duplicate dates to make more realistic
example.dat1$date[2] <- as.Date('2017/04/13') 
example.dat1$date[14] <- as.Date('2019/04/12')

# Calculate start and end date to define period of interest for each row -
# i.e for each row we want to identify every other row that falls within these 
# start and end dates
example.dat1 <- example.dat1 %>% mutate(start_date = date - years(1),
                      end_date = date + years(1))
```

This is my attempt at the solution

```
# Create new, empty data frame
example.dat2 <- data.frame()

example.dat2 <- for(i in 1:nrow(example.dat1))
{
  m = 0
  if(example.dat1$control.any == 1) {           #Condition that must be met
    start_date = example.dat1$start_date[i]     #If condition met read in start date and end date
    end_date = example.dat1$end_date[i]
    
    for(j in nrow(example.dat1))
    {
      record_date = example.dat1$date[j]       #Loop back through data and extract record date
      if(record_date > start_date & record_date < end_date)    #Test if record date falls within period defined by start and end date, and if so populate new data frame 
      m = m + 1
      {
        example.dat2$date1[m] <- example.dat1$date[i]
        example.dat2$Longitude1[m] <- example.dat1$Longitude[i]
        example.dat2$Latitude1[m] <- example.dat1$Latitude[i]
        example.dat2$rhdv1[m] <- example.dat1$rhdv[i]
        example.dat2$control.any1[m] <- example.dat1$control.any[i]
        example.dat2$start_date[m] <- start_date
        example.dat2$end_date[m] <- end_date
        
        example.dat2$date2[m] <- record_date
        example.dat2$Longitude2[m] <- example.dat1$Longitude[j]
        example.dat2$Latitude2[m] <- example.dat1$Latitude[j]
        example.dat2$rhdv2[m] <- example.dat1$rhdv[j]
        example.dat2$control.any2[m] <- example.dat1$control.any[j]
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Manually created solution to `example.dat1`

```
example.dat2 <- structure(list(Origional.row.num.dat1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), date1 = structure(c(17269, 
17269, 17269, 17269, 17269, 17269, 17269, 17269, 17269, 17269, 
16642, 18184, 18184, 18184, 18184, 18184, 17862, 17862, 17862, 
17862, 17862, 17862, 16822, 17432, 17432, 17432, 17432, 17432, 
17998, 17998, 17998, 17998, 17998), class = "Date"), Latitude1 = c(34.9173, 
34.9173, 34.9173, 34.9173, 34.9173, 34.9173, 34.9173, 34.9173, 
34.9173, 34.9173, 34.389, 34.0949, 34.0949, 34.0949, 34.0949, 
34.0949, 34.2193, 34.2193, 34.2193, 34.2193, 34.2193, 34.2193, 
34.3263, 35.6748, 35.6748, 35.6748, 35.6748, 35.6748, 34.8939, 
34.8939, 34.8939, 34.8939, 34.8939), Longitude1 = c(114.8124, 
114.8124, 114.8124, 114.8124, 114.8124, 114.8124, 114.8124, 114.8124, 
114.8124, 114.8124, 116.4014, 115.0311, 115.0311, 115.0311, 115.0311, 
115.0311, 115.4243, 115.4243, 115.4243, 115.4243, 115.4243, 115.4243, 
115.0247, 116.9052, 116.9052, 116.9052, 116.9052, 116.9052, 116.1216, 
116.1216, 116.1216, 116.1216, 116.1216), rhdv1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), control.any1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), start_date = structure(c(16904, 16904, 16904, 16904, 16904, 
16904, 16904, 16904, 16904, 16904, 16277, 17819, 17819, 17819, 
17819, 17819, 17497, 17497, 17497, 17497, 17497, 17497, 16457, 
17067, 17067, 17067, 17067, 17067, 17633, 17633, 17633, 17633, 
17633), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(17634, 17634, 
17634, 17634, 17634, 17634, 17634, 17634, 17634, 17634, 17008, 
18550, 18550, 18550, 18550, 18550, 18227, 18227, 18227, 18227, 
18227, 18227, 17188, 17797, 17797, 17797, 17797, 17797, 18364, 
18364, 18364, 18364, 18364), class = "Date"), Origional.row.num.dat1.1 = c(2L, 
4L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 
14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 11L, 13L), date2 = structure(c(17269, 17324, 17530, 17256, 
17432, 17269, 17324, 17530, 17256, 17432, 16822, 17962, 17862, 
17987, 17998, 17998, 18184, 17530, 17962, 17987, 17998, 17998, 
16822, 17269, 17269, 17324, 17530, 17256, 18184, 17962, 17862, 
17987, 17998), class = "Date"), Latitude2 = c(34.93, 34.2041, 
34.6412, 35.9241, 35.6748, 34.93, 34.2041, 34.6412, 35.9241, 
35.6748, 34.3263, 35.5413, 34.2193, 34.4343, 35.2903, 34.8939, 
34.0949, 34.6412, 35.5413, 34.4343, 35.2903, 34.8939, 34.3263, 
34.9173, 34.93, 34.2041, 34.6412, 35.9241, 34.0949, 35.5413, 
34.2193, 34.4343, 35.2903), Longitude2 = c(115.1386, 116.5442, 
116.1425, 116.7467, 116.9052, 115.1386, 116.5442, 116.1425, 116.7467, 
116.9052, 115.0247, 116.1583, 115.4243, 115.3115, 116.8798, 116.1216, 
115.0311, 116.1425, 116.1583, 115.3115, 116.8798, 116.1216, 115.0247, 
114.8124, 115.1386, 116.5442, 116.1425, 116.7467, 115.0311, 116.1583, 
115.4243, 115.3115, 116.8798), rhdv2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), control.any2 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = "data.frame")
```

From within `example.dat1` there were eight rows where `control.any == 1` and for each of these eight rows `example.dat2` identifies every other row within `example.dat1` for which the `date` fell within the `start_date` and `end_date` period for the index row (where `control.any == 1`).

In the manually created solution I have also included columns that indicate the original row or data from `example.dat1` that is being represented/repeated to help clarify my intention.

Comment: Can you at least give what you wanted vis-à-vis your nested loop? Your current example lacks the `dat2` output in your loop. And the dates in your example doesn't match to the data you provided.

Comment: You probably do not want to use for loops and if statements but a combination of [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) methods. Take alook at function `filter`, `mutate` and `left_join`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, editing the solution in response to your comment. The dimensions of your example.dat2 and the solution here are out by one, but as far as I understand you (and I think this problem could be presented a touch clearer!) this is what you want:

```
date_ranges <- example.dat1 %>%
  filter(control.any == 1)%>%
  select(end_date = date)%>%
  mutate(start_date = end_date - lubridate::years(1),
         .before = end_date)%>%
  arrange(start_date)

example.dat1 %>%
  nest(data = everything())%>%
  mutate(period_starts = list(date_ranges$start_date),
         period_ends = list(date_ranges$end_date))%>%
  unnest(c(period_starts, period_ends))%>%
  unnest(data)%>%
  filter(date >= period_starts & date <= period_ends)

# A tibble: 34 × 7
   date       Latitude Longitude  rhdv control.any period_starts period_ends
   <date>        <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <date>        <date>     
 1 2016-05-29     35.9      116.     0           1 2015-05-29    2016-05-29 
 2 2016-09-10     35.1      115.     1           1 2015-09-10    2016-09-10 
 3 2016-05-29     35.9      116.     0           1 2015-09-10    2016-09-10 
 4 2018-01-19     35.8      117.     0           1 2017-01-19    2018-01-19 
 5 2018-03-12     35.7      114.     1           0 2017-10-05    2018-10-05 
 6 2018-03-10     34.2      114.     0           0 2017-10-05    2018-10-05 
 7 2018-10-05     34.5      115.     0           1 2017-10-05    2018-10-05 
 8 2018-01-19     35.8      117.     0           1 2017-10-05    2018-10-05 
 9 2018-03-12     35.7      114.     1           0 2017-11-28    2018-11-28 
10 2018-03-10     34.2      114.     0           0 2017-11-28    2018-11-28 
# … with 24 more rows
```

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want to do:

```
library(tidyverse) 

tibble(dat1) %>%
  group_by(start_date, end_date)%>%
  mutate(group_id = row_number())%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(group_id == 1))%>%
  group_split(group)


# A tibble: 33 × 13
   UserEmail      State date       Latitude Longitude month  year  rhdv control.any start_date end_date   group_id
   <chr>          <chr> <date>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <date>     <date>        <int>
 1 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        1
 2 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        2
 3 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        3
 4 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        4
 5 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        5
 6 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        6
 7 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        7
 8 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        8
 9 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01        9
10 dlhandscombe@… VIC   2021-06-01    -38.3      142. 06     2021     0           1 2020-06-01 2022-06-01       10
# … with 23 more rows, and 1 more variable: group <int>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 17 × 13
   UserEmail     State date       Latitude Longitude month  year  rhdv control.any start_date end_date group_id
   <chr>         <chr> <date>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <date>     <date>      <int>
 1 data@phbg.org WA    2020-12-01    -32.2      116. 12     2020     1           0 NA         NA              1
 2 data@phbg.org WA    2020-12-01    -32.2      116. 12     2020     1           0 NA         NA              2
 3 data@phbg.org WA    2020-12-01    -32.3      116. 12     2020     1           0 NA         NA              3
 4 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -32.8      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA              4
 5 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -32.8      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA              5
 6 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -33.0      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA              6
 7 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -33.2      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA              7
 8 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -33.3      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA              8
 9 data@phbg.org WA    2021-06-01    -32.9      116. 06     2021     1           0 NA         NA              9
10 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -33.0      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA             10
11 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -33.0      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA             11
12 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -32.8      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA             12
13 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -32.8      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA             13
14 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -32.7      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA             14
15 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -32.7      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA             15
16 data@phbg.org WA    2020-11-01    -32.5      116. 11     2020     1           0 NA         NA             16
17 data@phbg.org WA    2021-06-01    -32.5      116. 06     2021     1           0 NA         NA             17
# … with 1 more variable: group <int>

[[3]]
# A tibble: 60 × 13
   UserEmail      State date       Latitude Longitude month  year  rhdv control.any start_date end_date   group_id
   <chr>          <chr> <date>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <date>     <date>        <int>
 1 rickmiddag@gm… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.3      142. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        1
 2 gordonheron@h… WA    2021-05-01    -32.3      117. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        2
 3 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.1      144. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        3
 4 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.1      144. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        4
 5 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.1      144. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        5
 6 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.1      144. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        6
 7 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.1      144. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        7
 8 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.1      144. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        8
 9 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.1      144. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01        9
10 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-05-01    -38.1      144. 05     2021     0           1 2020-05-01 2022-05-01       10
# … with 50 more rows, and 1 more variable: group <int>

[[4]]
# A tibble: 91 × 13
   UserEmail      State date       Latitude Longitude month  year  rhdv control.any start_date end_date   group_id
   <chr>          <chr> <date>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <date>     <date>        <int>
 1 rickmiddag@gm… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.3      142. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        1
 2 rickmiddag@gm… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.3      142. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        2
 3 rickmiddag@gm… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.3      142. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        3
 4 rickmiddag@gm… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.3      142. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        4
 5 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.1      144. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        5
 6 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.1      144. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        6
 7 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.1      144. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        7
 8 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.1      144. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        8
 9 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.1      144. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01        9
10 allwrightag@b… VIC   2021-04-01    -38.1      144. 04     2021     0           1 2020-04-01 2022-04-01       10
# … with 81 more rows, and 1 more variable: group <int>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to have a go, but this doesn't quite get the solution I was looking for. I have created a new and better example and will edit original post to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: Have amended the solution. Output dimensions are off by 1, but you should be able to refactor the code to get the precise output you were looking for?